# How to merge multiple applications into a single application

Tags: android

i have developed some applications like making call, add contact ,send sms  for blind people.

Now i want to merge them into single application like [Mobile accessibility demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.codefactory.android.app.ma.vocalizerenudemo&feature=search_result)

i want to make it to work similar to it. how to make it possible?? ,**how can i make the application speak when the user touches on it. how to integrate all the developed apps into single app and make them work when user touches a specific app.**

please provide me some tutorial links/sample codes to make these things possible..

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make each of your project an Android Library, then have a new Android project define the UI to select each single app.

Please read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) to learn how to make Library project.